# Does the help center's guidance regarding downvotes need to be changed for today's Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, help-center

Context: Just see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372078/are-we-really-practicing-a-culture-of-that-what-cant-be-answered-easily-should) question and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372119/etiquette-regarding-downvotes-and-close-votes) one.

As users with less than 10k rep can't see the questions I've linked to above, essentially I'd posted two questions on MSO where I asked for discussion on whether downvotes are being used in a way that's different than their intended purpose.

Essentially, I feel that [the policy regarding downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) is slightly outdated for Stack Overflow in particular. While it may be suitable for other smaller sites, it doesn't apply as well to SO for the reason below.

The Help Center implies (to me) that downvotes are reserved for the worst of questions, and that edits/comments/flags should be used in nearly all other cases. This is all well and good, until you realise that SO gets thousands of questions per day and many people choose to downvote posts which may be improvable but where the downvoter doesn't choose to spend time providing specific constructive criticism. Clearly the Help Center's policy can't apply to SO due to the sheer size of the site.

**Feature Request: Please update the Help Center's policy on downvoting to cope with the sheer size of SO.**

Comment: Keep in mind that users with less than 10K rep can't review your deleted questions. If you want to discuss something, please don't involve other questions that got deleted, or provide a quick summary of what's discussed and why it's relevant.

Comment: Before mass downvoting because "OP is posting another rant", please read it. OP does make a good point here.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It's kinda hard to explain! If you've seen the other questions, then you'll understand. They were quite lengthy and even they contained numerous links to other questions and posts. I'll try to put a summary but it's unlikely that it'll be sufficient.

Comment: @Stijn Thanks! Does the good point include the 'practice' I'd mentioned? If so, do you feel that I should roll back my edit? (I edited it out because I assumed that's what the downvotes were for)

Comment: Your question as-is is fine (to me at least).

Comment: Please note that the tooltip of the downvote button states: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". It might be good to include that in the help center page.

Comment: I do agree with the general gist of the question: since, with the whole welcoming/CoC changes we're discouraged from commenting to point out flaws and encouraged to just downvote/vote to close instead, the guidance on downvotes could use adjusting.

Comment: I think most people should downvote more, but I don't think changing the help center will change their behavior to any significant degree. I also think that encouraging people to downvote more may have them downvote the wrong types of questions (i.e. well-asked but basic ones).

Comment: You have to try VERY hard to get suspended because of meta posts:)   Opposing views are normal.

Comment: @MartinJames Considering the torrent of downvotes I'd received in the previous two questions, I don't feel like it'd be much of a stretch to be suspended :)

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank So it's fair to say the 'practice' I mention *is* a 'done thing'? I phrased it the way I did because I was expecting people to contradict it, which some had done on my previous posts.

Comment: I'm not actually too sure what you're proposing we change the policy *to*. From a quick skim through your question, I thought you were asking for it to be made more relaxed about downvoting (downvote stuff that's mildly bad, because that would help deal with the sheer number of posts we get), but, purely based on the posts you linked to (or at least a quick skim of them), this doesn't really seem to add up and it seems like you're asking for something else (but I'm not sure what).

Comment: @Dukeling I'd referred to the links (the first one which has been undeleted isn't as helpful here) as in the comments people state and imply that they downvote after a few seconds of reading (which doesn't follow the Help Centre's policy). However, they seem to have a reasonable argument, which is why I'm suggesting that the policy is changed so that the current 'practice' is seen as appropriate by the Help Centre's policy. If it's not clear, do you think I should edit it?

Comment: I still don't understand why you think most people aren't reading enough before voting.

Comment: @BSMP a) People are admitting to it and it's a 'done thing' now b) I assumed people were following the policy of the Help Center regarding downvoting, but people saying that they only need a few seconds to decide whether to vote and people saying that they don't have enough time to edit/comment suggests otherwise :)

Comment: It often only takes a few seconds to identify "an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post" (quote from help center), so I still don't see the problem with the current phrasing. Also, what are you hoping to achieve here? Some people *already* only spend a few seconds on a post before downvoting, so changing the help center to reflect this fact will not do anything apart from possible encourage *more* people to do it (but those people may do so in a more sloppy manner).

Comment: @Dukeling I agree about how much time it takes. But my point is, people aren't following the Help Centre's policy regarding downvotes anyway because there's too many questions and too little time, so either the Help Center policy should be changed to reflect this (as it's already outdated and only applies for smaller sites), or people should do less DVing and more editing/commenting (which seems unlikely to happen as people seem extremely reluctant to do so due to abusive comments as well as time constraints)

Comment: @fbueckert For the last time, *I'm not trying to dictate actions*! If you read my previous comment, you can see that I'm suggesting exactly as you say: to amend the policy in the Help Centre.

Comment: I'm baffled by your summarizing your last post(s) by saying that "many users seemed to believe that there isn't enough time to thoroughly read through questions before voting on them". That's... really and truly not the feedback that people were giving you, which can be confirmed by reading through the now-undeleted post. What was largely being asserted was that there's not time to always *give detailed feedback* on every post. Nobody was claiming that they were downvoting without fully reading posts. I'm not sure why you're still trying so hard to put those words in others' mouths.

Comment: You've got a good suggestion otherwise - the help center text probably could use an update to clarify how downvoting is used today. But I really think that if you want to win people to your side, you need to let go of this misrepresentation of the discussion that's been had. People aren't attacking you personally, and you aren't going to get suspended for being disagreed with on Meta. Just try to have a debate in good faith.

Comment: @Adi219 ["Dictate: lay down authoritatively; prescribe."](https://www.google.ca/search?q=dictate). You, are trying, to make other people, act in a different way, based on your experiences, many and many times now, both in how we vote, but also how we use our close votes. Hell, read the definition! If you dislike the idea that you are prescribing / dictating something, ***stop doing it, don't try to change the meaning of the word***.

Comment: On your other question, you've edited in a whole paragraph about how we should not even use close votes since the question had been reopened. You tried time and again to tell how we should vote, or not, or read before voting. These things, in english, are called trying to tell other people how they should act. If you can't stand being perceived as doing that, then change how you act, stop trying to hide behind words.

Comment: @SamHanley Like I say in my first reply to Dukeling, the first link isn't as helpful in this case. However, people *are* saying that they only need to spend a few seconds reviewing posts and that they prefer to edit/comment, even on the first post.

Comment: There's a huge and critical difference in saying that "I only **need** a few seconds of review to tell which way to vote on a post" and saying "I **don't have enough time** to make informed votes", as many other people have been trying to explain. Those two statements are absolutely not the same - nearly the opposite, truthfully.

Comment: I initially upvoted the question because I think that updating the help page to better reflect how downvotes are currently used is a good thing. But then you edited in the last paragraph (and some others too) with which I don't agree with. If you want to get something changed, then try to do it one at a time. I would be happy if I could upvote just the adjust help center part, but I really don't want to upvote the rest.

Comment: It does read like a rant now though

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I disagree with your first comment but regarding your second comment, you're right, I shouldn't have said that. All I was trying to say was that there wasn't much point in keeping on trying to get it closed.

Comment: @BDL TBF I *did* say that it's not essential or necessary, and I *did* have my reservations about editing it in. I'll remove it now.

Comment: @Magisch You're right, please see my comment above.

Comment: That edit was a big step in the right direction. If you also consider editing to remove any misrepresentation of what others have asserted in your previous discussions, you'd be approaching something that I could upvote in good conscience.

Comment: @SamHanley Could you edit it instead? Because, honestly, I'm having so many discussions that I'm getting confused between what's the problem in this post. Thanks!

Comment: @Adi219 sure thing, I've edited it to reflect what I think is a fairer summation of the community's discussion in your previous posts. I hope that you consider how it better aligns with what people were actually expressing, and that it helps allow a more focused discussion of the (pretty valid!) specific suggestion you're making.

Comment: @SamHanley I felt that people were getting sidetracked by my choice of words. Thanks!

Comment: @Adi219 The problem with the post was not how it was worded it, it was what you were saying.  You made numerous statement that were not only factually false, but were completely misrepresenting others by claiming they said the opposite of what they actually said, such misrepresentation so egregious basically needs to be malicious.

Comment: @Servy Would choice of statements be more appropriate then?

Comment: @Adi219 I go over the numerous erroneous claims that you've made, and what the statements the claim to represent actually are, in my answer.

Comment: @Stijn 18 upvotes, 21 downvotes, it seems like people aren't reading your comment :(

Comment: @Adi219 That, or maybe people read your question and disagree with you. It is also unclear what is the change to the help section you would like to add.

Comment: @Adi219 Also you have a reopen vote regarding your own question. Btw, fixing the voting moral is... might be a good opportunity to make the sites more welcoming and friendly. The main problem is that the SE wants to produce *useful* content, i.e. content which is voted up. It is like if you have a company, no customer has to explain, why they don't buy your product. You simply have to produce such goods what they want to buy. And also the SE is a business, its product is the content what we produce. Prescribing the users how to vote would work, but it would contradict this feature.

Comment: @Adi219 This is why the SE has only very few really enforced regulations, how people vote. Unfortunately, some people clearly misuse it, which is visible even on their profile page. You can't do too much to them, but fortunately they are not enough to a significant effect. Their votes are like the rain, no one can say where the next drop will fall.

Answer (score 22):

> many users seemed to believe that there isn't enough time to thoroughly read through questions before voting on them.

Nobody told you that.  This is a complete misrepresentation of what you were told.

People told you that they are able to accurately judge the quality of a question without needing to read the whole thing.  People told you that it's not worth their time to spend considerable effort trying to help users fix truly terrible posts, and that their time is better spent merely indicating that the post is problematic and then moving on to posts that are either salvageable, or already good.  Neither of those things are what you're describing.

Of course, no one could possibly actually evaluate the quality of every post on the site.  Even if they could, they couldn't reflect that opinion with their votes as users are only allowed to vote on 40 questions in a day anyway.

The only thing people told you in that question was that your assertion that people don't read questions before voting on them is wrong, and that your evidence that people don't read questions before voting was flawed and doesn't support your position at all.  That you're continuing to assert that people are voting on questions without reading them, and asserting that people are telling you that they do that, despite them *saying literally the opposite* moves from misleading into outright deception, and is frankly inexcusable.

> The Help Center implies (to me) that downvotes are reserved for the worst of questions, and that edits/comments/flags should be used in nearly all other cases.

What's your basis for assuming that any of those things are substitutes for providing your opinion on the quality of a post?  Edits are there to improve a post.  Comments are there to inform the author on how it can be improved.  Flags are there to indicate that some moderation action is required.  None of those things are substitutes for indicating the quality of a post.

> It seems to have become common practice (at least, in my opinion and experiences) to skim through a question for mere seconds before downvoting

Again, you've continued to assert this to be true, despite all of the (very little) evidence that you've provided supporting the *opposing* position.

> instead of commmenting/editing

Again, these are not mutually exclusive actions.  No one is forcing people to *either* vote *or* comment *or* edit.  You can do any combination of those things.  You can do *all* of those things.  That you commented on a post doesn't mean you no longer need to reflect your opinion of the post's quality.  It's still just as useful with the comment as it is without it.

---

As far as the actual guidance in the help center, it's...not the greatest.  Far and away the best description of what downvotes are for, in my eyes, is the downvote tool tip, so I would most certainly start there with, "This answer[/question] is not useful."

There are lots of things that can make an answer not useful.  *One* of them is a post being incorrect, but there are lots of other reasons.  Additionally, the amount of *effort* is not really relevant.  What matters is how useful it is.  Some people can write a super useful post with basically no effort, some people can write a truly *terrible* post despite spending considerable effort.  How hard they tried is irrelevant, how useful the post is to others is what matters.

The quote, "You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes cost you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely." is a better one.  There are lots of bad posts out there, and you *are* limited in your votes.  Now most users don't actually use up their votes in a day, so I don't know if it's important enough to have here, but for those voting a lot, it is more useful to downvote the worst of the posts that you see.

As far as the end of the article, saying, "It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing," is great, and certainly true.  Just because you've indicated that a post isn't useful doesn't mean you shouldn't also try to help the author improve it, if you feel that you'll be able to do so.  The main problem is the one word shortly following it, "Instead of voting down:", it's that word "instead" that's just plain wrong.  It should say, "In addition to voting down", because none of those actions are orthogonal to voting, and none of those actions are reasons to not downvote if the post isn't useful.

Comment: "the amount of effort is not really relevant" - do you mean for questions or answers? The paragraph seems to be about answers, but I imagine some could say this applies to questions as well (even if it's arguable).

Comment: @Dukeling It's not what matters in the end.  At the end of the day, what matters is how useful a post is.  That said, people that put more effort into their post are much more likely to have a useful post.  People that put very little effort into their post are much less likely to have a useful post.  They're correlated.  So when giving someone advice on how to write a post, it's *great* advice to tell them to put a lot of effort in, but that's because it typically results in the post *being more useful*.  It's the *result* of that action that determines how it should be voted on.

Comment: On the one hand I agree that a question with zero effort displayed could be very useful, and some of our top-voted posts fall into that category, but on the other hand it sets a *really* bad precedent regarding allowing questions that are duplicates, doesn't contain an MCVE, belongs on a different site or really whatever else is a valid reason for closing a question. Usefulness is super vague and subjective and it sends a really confusing message about what we actually want questions to look like.

Comment: The post's been edited, so sections of this answer no longer stand.

Comment: @Adi219 The fact that other people have edited the post to radically change your claims doesn't change the fact that you've made those claims, repeatedly.

Comment: @Servy Other people made the edits because I asked them to. And in fact, I'd only asked one person to make an edit. Actually, only two/three times. Also, I'd back the claims but I'm tired of arguing so I'm leaving it at that.

Comment: @Dukeling Which is why I most certainly wouldn't want it to say something like "effort doesn't matter" or anything like that.  The point is that the actual voting criteria is to vote on how useful a post is.  You can say things like, "people that put very little effort into a post are much less likely to have a useful post" and have them to be true, but it's inappropriate to say, "you should vote on how much effort someone put into a post".

Comment: To use your more specific example, saying, "this question isn't useful because a reasonable amount of research will let you find this answer" is fine.  It's not a commentary on how much research the author *actually did*.  If someone did no research, but no research would have found them the answer, the post is still useful.  If someone put no effort into making an MCVE but their program was just *inherently* a good MCVE already, it's still useful, etc.

Comment: @Dukeling So in the end the sections on the help center on how to write a post should say things like, "Do your research" and "Take the time to construct an MCVE", but the guidelines on voting should focus on how useful the end result of the question is, regardless of how the author got there.

Comment: @Adi219 Remember what I said about making statements and providing proof?  It applies here, too.  Making baseless statements is just asking for others to call you on them.  I don't think there's any proof to back up your statements, in any case.

Comment: @Servy But if someone comes to Stack Overflow and sees a bunch of no-research posts that are received well, they'll believe that's fine and proceed to ask a no-research question and probably get downvoted into oblivion. Understanding what makes a post useful is much harder than understanding "do research or get downvoted".

Comment: @Adi219 I don't see how the fact that you told someone else to edit your post is relevant here.  You made egregiously wrong statements.  Telling someone else to fix it for you because you're unwilling or unable to do so yourself isn't a reason for me to not explain what you stated, why it's wrong, and what it should be. If you edited it yourself (indicating you understood your mistake and were able to correct it) then that would make it irrelevant in my answer.

Comment: @Dukeling How are you going to assert that a given post wasn't well researched if no amount of research would have found the answer?  You have no way of knowing if the author of a given question did a bunch of research and didn't find anything, or if they just didn't do any research.  You just know how discoverable the answer to their question is, and whether they've demonstrated having the tools to find the answer themselves.  This is precisely why "effort" is a bad metric for evaluating quality, even though it's good advice for someone asking a question, as effort isn't always visible.

Comment: @Servy Effort is not a good metric for quality, I agree, but enforcing showing effort could increase overall quality and help make it clear what a (potentially) "good" question looks like, in a manner that people can actually understand (it doesn't help much if we say people should do research, but the site is filled with questions that show no research - who will listen to that advice?).

Comment: @Dukeling Which is why I've said, several times now, that it's appropriate to tell people that it's important that they put a suitable amount of effort in for the articles on how to author a post, because it *is* good advice for those people.  It's just not good to tell people to use it as metric for evaluating another's post.  I'm not saying "effort" should be removed from the whole help center.

Comment: @Servy I'm assuming a large portion (if not the majority) of people have, at some point, read another question or two, where-as most people probably *don't* read the help center, nor anything else we might ask them to read prior to asking a question (never mind actually *listen* to what's written there).

Comment: @Dukeling So you're saying that you think it would be a good idea for people to downvote useful posts if they assume that the OP didn't put in a lot of effort, and upvote posts that aren't useful if they think that the OP put in a lot of effort, even though it's very difficult, if not impossible, to accurately judge how much effort someone has put into a question, because that will encourage other people to put more effort into their questions? I...just can't support that.  If that's not what you're suggesting, then I'm confused, and you need to clarify.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I'm saying it could work to *require* people to show reasonable effort in their posts, **in theory**. But I do see the practical problems with that. I personally do, however, rarely downvote, because (among other reasons) I can't come up with something remotely objective to differentiate +1000 and -5 questions (and if it's supposed to be subjective, I'll just stick to downvoting the basically-or-literally-spam 0.02% instead of downvoting the 99.99% which all seem basically equivalent to me in terms of usefulness).

Comment: @Servy Posting links to similar questions or one's attempt would make (some of) the research done very clear. I'm not saying we're supposed to judge posts based on some imagined gauge of the research done, but rather based on what's visible in the post.

Comment: @Dukeling And that's all good advice to give people in the how to ask.  Often including such information can improve a post.  But lots of posts don't benefit from that type of content, and lots of posts are still quite useful, even if there are changes that they could make to make them *more* useful than they currently are.